# How to make an assertion based on class name in web driver

Tags: webdriver, selenium-webdriver

The HTML is as follows:

```html
<section class="my-account-box-element">
    <span class="item icon-home icon-color-1"></span>
</section>
```

Need to make an assertion based on the class name which changes from 'icon-home icon-color-1' to 'icon-home icon-color-0' depending upon the condition.

Comment: Not sure i understood your question, what you are looking for here is a Assert, or maybe a way to identify how to manipulate the element based on its class?

Comment: Yes, how to manipulate "item icon-home icon-color-1" based on class name. item icon-home icon-color-1 means true and item icon-home icon-color-0 means false.

Comment: I've provided a answer, let me know it that helps you in any way, hopefully i understood your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First i must warn that you can't add two classes when searching for it using the `By`, since *'item'*, *'item-home'* on your example are the same. I'm going to assume the main difference is in *'item-color-1'* and *'item-color-0'*.

```java
WebElement myAccountBoxElement = driver.findElement(By.className("my-account-box-element"));
WebElement spanItem = myAccountBoxElement.findElement(By.tagName("span"));
boolean itemColor = (spanItem.getAttribute("class").contains("item-color-1")) ? true : false;

if (itemColor) {
    // do stuff for item-color-1 element
}
    // do stuff for the item-color-0 element
}
```

The above code should work flawlessly provided the above code is the actual HTML, if there are more  tags, use `findElements()` instead and loop in it.

Also i went with a ternary if since it keeps a cleaner code, providing you are only working with those two elements

Answer (score 0):

change as per your needs

```
assertTrue(driver.findElements( By.Xpath(".//span[contains(@class,'icon-color-1')]")).size() != 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can also use this

```
By.className("classname");
boolean isElementPresent = driver.findElement(By.className("classname"));
```